# Connection refused in testing feign client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I need to check the propagation of headers so I need to test my feign client.

What I did was:

1)Define a controller:

```
  @RestController
  public class Controller{

   @GetMapping("/api")
   public MyResponse callApi(){

   }
}
```

2) Define feign:

```
@FeignClient(name="anApi", url="http://localhost:8080", configuration=MyConfig.class)
public interface MyFeign {
```

3) Do my test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest{

    @Test
    public void myTest{
      client.callApi();
    }
 }
```

But I get a connection refused, it's like there is no controller listening...

Comment: Any progress on this? Thanks!

Comment: In the end I just mocked the configuration...couldn't get it to work

Comment: Phate, how mocked, with a different Profile or config?

Comment: I just used plain mockito!